# Speeding up UMAP

Tags: python, machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I have a situation similar to the one that was discussed in an old [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257096/python-make-umap-faster) where the number of features was 1.2M (mine 10M) but only hundreds of observations. Among `metric`s I tried, `euclidean` performed poorly but `cosine` and `correlation` were much better. I also noticed that it was only at the end, and that too for barely a few seconds, >100% CPU was being used while my system has 256 cores. For the most part, only a single core was being used, presumably for the metric computation. While I would have preferred UMAP scaling well, but I tried addressing the issue through NumPy (which I believe can use multiple cores for computation).

I tried the following approach:

Original function:

```
import umap
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

metric = 'cosine' # alternatively 'correlation'
scaler = StandardScaler()
ip_std = scaler.fit_transform(ip_mat)

# Start UMAP
reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=n_components, n_neighbors=n_neighbors, metric=metric)
umap_embed = reducer.fit_transform(ip_std)
```

Modified version:

```
import umap
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from umap.umap_ import nearest_neighbors

# Start precomputed_knn

scaler = StandardScaler()
eiip_std = scaler.fit_transform(eiip_mat)

dist_cosine = 1 - pairwise_distances(eiip_std, metric="cosine")
precomputed_knn = nearest_neighbors(dist_cosine, metric="cosine", \
                                      metric_kwds=None, angular=False, \
                                      n_neighbors=n_neighbors, random_state=42)
# Start UMAP
reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=n_components, precomputed_knn=precomputed_knn)
umap_embed = reducer.fit_transform(eiip_std)

return umap_embed
```

While I got no errors, the output was not of `cosine` at all but of the default `euclidian`.

Could you please point to the mistake in the above code and suggest any improvements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the [metric](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#umap) as 'cosine' so the reducer in your code becomes:

```
reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=n_components, metric='cosine', precomputed_knn=precomputed_knn)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was following the example on UMAP page (https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/precomputed_k-nn.html) so I thought that precomputed metric will be used.